# any idea why my getColumnIndex() is returning -1 via android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

```
public int getUserCred(User user){
 database = opener.getReadableDatabase();

 String first = user.getFirst();
 String pass = user.getPassword();
 String[] cols = {COL_FIRST, COL_PASS};

userCursor = database.query(TABLE_USER, cols, null, null, null, null, null);

if(userCursor != null & userCursor.moveToFirst()) {
       String firstName =   userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(COL_FIRST));
        String password =  userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(COL_PASS));
            if(first.equals(firstName) & pass.equals(password)){
               return User.CRED_CORRECT;
              }
           }

     database.close();
   userCursor.close();
  return User.CRED_INCORRECT;
}
```

There's my code as it is now, though an `illegalStateException` keeps getting thrown at me saying it can't access row 0 col -1. Now I know in fact the data is held in the cursor because `cursor.getString(0)` and `cursor.getString(1)` is returning the data, but using `cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_(FIRST/PASS))` keeps raising the exception.

Can somebody please explain to me why it's doing this to me? Originally I held all SQLITE schema statements in an interface, which is what I thought was causing the problem for some reason, but then putting them in a nested class raised the same exception, so I decided to make them class variables in my SQLiteOpenHelper subclass. However, that still didn't change my `getColumnIndex()` situation I got going on. 
So if someone can point me in the right direction I'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: What are the values of `COL_FIRST` and `COL_PASS`?

Comment: @dave COL_FIRST = "FIRSTNAME " COL_PASS = "PASSWORD "; with the leading whitespaces.

Comment: Could you list the column names in table `TABLE_USER `? It seems `COL_FIRST` and `COL_PASS` don't match those columns in the table.

Comment: _ID, COL_FIRST, and COL_PASS

Comment: No column `COL_PASS`?

Comment: getColumnIndex() is case sensitive, make sure both `COL_FIRST` and `COL_PASS` are same as column name in DB

Comment: @cwfei they are the same case

Comment: @shhp there is a COL_PASS

Comment: Try removing the leading space

Comment: Try to eliminate whitespaces in `COL_FIRST ` and `COL_PASS `.

Comment: i did now it's telling me no such table exist :/

Comment: @shhp i removed whitespaces, and after fiddling around with the schema it worked. i still don't entirely know why it worked but thank you for helping me!

Comment: When you create a table the whitespaces in the column name will be ignored. So when you query the table you should not add whitespaces to column names.

Comment: @shhp thank you for that. that will definitely prove to be useful in my next app

Answer (score 1):

> COL_FIRST = "FIRSTNAME " COL_PASS = "PASSWORD "; with the leading whitespaces

The problem is the whitespace and implementation details.

Extra whitespace doesn't matter when the strings are used as part of SQL string. This happens when using e.g. in `query()` - essentially the args are just concatenated together to form an SQL string and sqlite parses it correctly even with extra whitespace.

`Cursor#getColumnIndex()` is an interface method but let's assume the usual [`SQLiteCursor` implementation](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java#165). It does not work on SQL level. The column names and indices as reported by sqlite are put in a `Map` and then looked up with the given column name. This means that the column name must match *exactly* what the column name is to sqlite. Specifically:

- Surrounding whitespace are not part of the column name.
- `Map` lookup by key is case sensitive while SQL itself is not.